# Reformat these lines in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've this type of data :

```
Name        : Monday
Description : XXX
Type    : Day 1
XXX          : XXX
XXX         : XXX


Name        : Tuesday
Description : XXX
Type    : Day 2
XXX          : XXX
XXX         : XXX


Name        : Wednesday
Description : XXX
Type    : Day 3
XXX          : XXX
XXX         : XXX
```

I'm able to keep only the Name and the Type :

```
$file = "D:\XXX\test.txt"

$data = Get-Content $file

foreach($i in $data){

   $Name = $i | findstr /c:"Name"
   $Type = $i | findstr /c:"Type"

   Write-Output $Name
   Write-Output $Type
}
```

The output is :

```
Name        : Monday
Type    : Day 1
Name        : Tuesday
Type    : Day 2
Name        : Wednesday
Type    : Day 3
```

But I would like this output :

```
Monday/Day 1
Tuesday/Day 2
Wednesday/Day 3
```

I know how to do that in bash but I'm totally lost with powershell...

Is there someone who can show me how to do that?

Comment: why do you use `findstr` in powershell instead of `sls`?

Comment: cross posted: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/vzjio4/reformat_some_lines_in_powershell/

Answer (score 1):

If your data is always separated by 2 new lines like that then simply split the string into multiple sections then parse it using [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1)

```
(Get-Content $file -Delimiter "`n`n`n") | ForEach-Object {
    $d = $_ | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':'
    Write-Host ($d["Name"] + '/' + $d["Type"])
}
```

Aliased version:

```
(gc $file -Del "`n`n`n") |% { $d = $_ | ConvertFrom-StringData -D ':'; $d["Name"] + '/' + $d["Type"] }
```

Note that this requires **PowerShell Core 7.0**

If there's only an empty line between sections then just change the delimiter from `` "`n`n`n" `` to `` "`n`n" ``

---

Solution for **PowerShell older than 7.0**:

```
((gc $file -Del "`n`n`n") -replace ':', '=') |% `
    { $d = ConvertFrom-StringData $_; $d["Name"] + '/' + $d["Type"] }
```

Alternate method:

```
(((gc $file -Raw) -replace ':', '=') -split "`n`n`n" ) |% `
    { $d = ConvertFrom-StringData $_; $d["Name"] + '/' + $d["Type"] }
```

[Demo on TIO](https://tio.run/##nZBBi8IwEIXv@RWPUImiZXH3VunJ4k0vCrYssgY7aKFNQhpdivrba7sriJ6KMzCHjzfvDWP0L9nyQHle132@kAXhXgHmWqWyYhGVO5sZl2nVwDiO2aoy9C@JZIUxaxjw2GslSZK8EMae3VdHKrvYf75nv6ZUdQv46hTA4VsyudwRRCBGEKEYwC9NnjnwrWqb49LDGV6KEFOtTmTdzOrCXzqbqX0knYT3M0HfS7//Ps03GEJ8iGa2qL2Kbwa41vUN)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a regex, like so:

```
$regex = [Regex]::new('\bName\b\s*\:\s*(?<Name>.*)[\S\s]*?\bType\b\s*\:\s*(?<Type>.*)')
$fileContents = @'    
    Name        : Monday
    Description : XXX
    Type    : Day 1
    XXX          : XXX
    XXX         : XXX
    
    
    Name        : Tuesday
    Description : XXX
    Type    : Day 2
    XXX          : XXX
    XXX         : XXX
    
    
    Name        : Wednesday
    Description : XXX
    Type    : Day 3
    XXX          : XXX
    XXX         : XXX
'@ 
$regex.Matches($fileContents) | %{"$($_.Groups['Name'].Value)/$($_.Groups['Type'].Value)"}
```

NB: You'd need to tweak your code a little for this to work with it; as currently `$data` will be an array of strings, rather than a single string.

Amend `$data = Get-Content $file` to `$data = Get-Content $file -Raw` to read the input as a single, multi-line, string.